# При установке Gulp плагина, подтягиваются "куча" модулей nodeJS, в чём дело?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Недавно перешел на NodeJS 5. Для банальной компиляции установил в проект Gulp и один плагин для него, установка длилась неожиданно долго, и в итоге в папку "node_modules", свалилось аж 246 модулей. От куда они и зачем?

Это нововведения NodeJS 5 версии, и как с этим теперь жить? (бороться или принять как данность), если бороться, то как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это зависимости галпа наверное..

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но в 4-ке, всё красиво укладывалось в node_modules отдельного плагина, да в принципе и здесь всё так же, но помимо остального, ещё и эта куча модулей. Прилагаю скриншот.

Comment: Это npm3. Читайте доки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы выразились "куча" модулей появилась не из-за перехода к `node@5.x.x` а из-за перехода к `npm@3.x.x`.

Раньше `npm@2.x.x` использовал вложенные каталоги `node_modules` для каждого из модулей. Это позволяло полностью изолировать зависимости модулей. С другой стороны, это приводило и к существенному раздуванию каталога `node_modules`. Одна и та же зависимость в одной и той же версии могла дублироваться очень большое количество раз в разных местах дерева зависимостей.

В новой версии npm изменил подход к разделению зависимостей. Теперь все дерево зависимостей "расплющивается" и помещается в `node_modules` вашего приложения. В том случае, если появляется конфликт версий зависимостей, то они по-старинке помещаются во вложенный каталог `node_modules`. Этот вариант позволяет с одной стороны использовать правильные версии модулей, а с другой - сократить объем кодовой базы.

Таким образом, вся та "куча" модулей, что вы видите, это зависимости `gulp`, зависимости зависимостей `gulp`, зависимости зависимостей зависимостей `gulp` и так далее. Бояться этого не нужно. Более того, вам вообще не нужно заботиться о содержимом папки `node_modules` - об этом должен думать npm.

**Резюме:**

Ничего страшного в существовании этих модулей нет. Смиритесь.